# Extent ActionText::RichText to override table_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

`ActionText::RichText` class has table name [hard coded](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actiontext/app/models/action_text/rich_text.rb) in Rails code.

```
self.table_name = "action_text_rich_texts"
```

It ignores `table_name_prefix` setting and makes it not possible to have a table name `project_a_action_text_rich_texts` work.

Is there a way to override `table_name` that's coming from Rails class `ActionText::RichText`?

**Update**: Updating two apps to Rails 6.x that share the same database in the cloud but use `table_name_prefix` to have separate set of tables.

In Rails, table names for `ActionText` and `ActiveStorage` are hard coded. Goal is to make Project A read `project_a_action_text_` and Project B read `project_b_action_` tables.

Comment: Monkeypatch it? But that will most likely just break a bunch of assocations and other code. Why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: @max Upgrading an old app to that uses `table_name_prefix` and share cloud db with another project (i know ). It's the same problem with `ActionStorage`. There was a fix but it was not added to 6.x and is planned to come with 7 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35811) it will be fixed at least for `ActiveStorage` in Rails 7

Until then I used the following patch to override `table_name` in `ActionText` and `ActiveStorage`. Make sure to verify it's working (or remove it) when you upgrade Rails to 7.

Here's the example for `ActionText`

First create a module in `lib` folder and set new `table_name`

```
#lib/extensions/action_text_rich_text.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
module Extensions::ActionTextRichText
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def table_name
    'project_a_action_text_rich_texts'
  end  
end
```

Create a new initializer and add extension module to `ActionText`

```
#config/initializers/extensions.rb
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  ActionText::RichText.extend Extensions::ActionTextRichText    
end
```

It will override `table_name` set in Rails `ActionText` module.
Now you can update table name in `ActionText` migration generated by Rails and run the migration.

You can test by calling `ActionText::RichText.table_name` in Rails console. It should print new table name that you set in your extension.